# where to put log4j.properties- for use in java desktop app

Tags: log4j

I am trying to use log4j logging framework in a java desktop application.

When I run the code I am getting a message

```
log4j: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
```

I googled for the above error and found that it occurs when the log4j.properties file is not found by the app.

I am creating the desktop app using Eclipse. Currently log4j.properties is within the same folder that contains the source (in 'src' folder). Where should I put this file to make it work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

log4j will use a [Default Initialization Procedure](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit) to find your configuration file. The documentation notes:

*The preferred way to specify the default initialization file is through the **log4j.configuration** system property*

If this property is not set - log4j will look at the classpath. In your case you have to place the file in the `src` directory (assumed that the content will be put in the classes path while you build the system). If you use maven place the file to the `src/main/resources` directory.

As you placed your file to the src directory check, that the file get transferred to the top level directory of your compiled classes.

Comment: There was a config for allowing output folders for source folders, that i had to select as applicable (in Java Build Path in Eclipse->Project Settings)... After that the log4j.properties file (which was in src) was picked up and log4j works now without any problem. Thanks a lot for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Keep the properties file in the classes folder i.e. the folder that contains the classes (specially the main class).
Another reason for getting this error may be the wrong appenders or an appender without setting.

Comment: @Naved- ok, the main class in my app is com.arvind.gdata.(within src/com/arvind/)... So should I put the properties file within src/com/arvind/ ?? Thanks...

Comment: Put it in the folder where .class file is present like classes/com/arvind/gdata.